# $cookies with angularjs 1.4 expiration date

Tags: angularjs, cookies, angular-cookies

How do i set the cookie with expiration date with angularjs 1.4. The documentation says to use

```
expires - {string|Date} - String of the form "Wdy, DD Mon YYYY HH:MM:SS GMT" or a Date object indicating the exact date/time this cookie will expire.
```

But its not working.My firebug is showing the expiration date as Session only.

**HTML**

```
<div ng-app="cookieApp" ng-controller="cookieCtrl">
    <button ng-click="setCookie()">Set Cookie</button>
     <button ng-click="getCookie()">Get Cookie</button>
</div>
```

**Javascript**

```
    var app=angular.module("cookieApp",['ngCookies']);
app.controller("cookieCtrl",function($scope, $cookies){
    $scope.setCookie = function(){
    console.log("setCookie");
        var now = new Date();
        now.setDate(now.getDate() + 7);
          $cookies.put("tech","angularjs",{expiry:now});
     }
     $scope.getCookie = function(){
          alert( $cookies.get("tech"));
    }
});
```

I tried to set the jsFiddle but i couldnt save it. My alert is showing undefined.

Answer (score 6):

Ran into your problem debugging something similar.

The main bug was due to `expiry` vs `expires` in your code.

```
var app = angular.module("cookieApp", ["ngCookies"]);
app.controller("cookieCtrl", function ($scope, $cookies) {
    $scope.setCookie = function () {
        console.log("setCookie");

        var now = new Date();
        now.setDate(now.getDate() + 7);

        $cookies.put("tech", "angularjs", {
            expires: now
        });
    }
    $scope.getCookie = function () {
        alert($cookies.get("tech"));
    }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/ucskyv67/

Note the two dependencies on `angular.js` and `angular-cookies.js` - linked in the side bar - I've linked to 1.4.2 on google's cdn.

Answer (score 3):

Use this one modified library of angular-cookies.
In this you can set cookies with passing object of expires and path also

https://github.com/babarxm/angular-cookies-fixed/tree/v1.5.6

Example:

```
$cookies.put("token", {
    expires : new Date(),
    path : "/somepath"
});
```

Set the hours, mins, days of date object to set cookies expiring.
default will be session.

(sorry for bad english :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer.But i am out of 1.x version and tryingout 2.x version with type script. I will keep you notified and appreciate your response.

Answer (score 2):

I have run into this issue with firefox not saving cookies. According to the doc https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies, the correct cookie call should be :

```
$cookies.put("tech","angularjs",[{expires:now}]);
```

note the "expires vs expiry and the [] wrapping args.

Comment: Square brackets are not needed.